# Within a rack application, how can I tell which web server is running?

Tags: ruby, rack

Within a rack application, how can I tell which web server is running as the Rack Handler?

For instance, from within config.ru, I want to switch on whether I am running WEBrick:

```
unless running_webrick?
  redirect_stdout_and_stderr_to_file
end

run App
```

```
def running_webrick?
   ???
end
```

Comment: I wonder this might helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193635/change-default-server-for-rails

Answer (score 0):

The environment hash passed to every component in the stack has a `SERVER_SOFTWARE` key.  Run this and observe the output on the web page:

```
require 'rack'

class EnvPrinter

  def call env
    [200, {'content-type' => 'text/plain'}, [env.inspect]]
  end

end

run EnvPrinter.new
```

If executed with rackup, the webrick will be used as the server (it's the default) and `SERVER_SOFTWARE` will be something like `WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2013-01-15)`.  If unicorn is used it will be something like `Unicorn 4.5.0`.  This rackup code returns a custom response based on which server it is running on:

```
require 'rack'

class EnvPrinter

  def call env
    response = case env.fetch('SERVER_SOFTWARE')
               when /webrick/i then 'Running on webrick'
               when /unicorn/i then 'Running on unicorn'
               when /thin/i then 'Running on thin'
               else "I don't recognize this server"
               end
    [200, {'content-type' => 'text/plain'}, [response]]
  end

end

run EnvPrinter.new
```